# Can one make GitLab CI cross compile build stage and test stage run on separate environment?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cross-compiling, continuous-deployment

We want to adopt CI/CD in a project that should be deployed on an armv7 SoC. The legacy workflow is like:

cross compile the project on the x86 dev server -> copy the executable to a dev board -> run the executable with some test case(by hand)

We manage the project by GitLab. To automate the whole process, we want to use GitLab CI, Generally the CI has only two stages:

```yaml
stages:
 - build
 - test

armv7-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build
    - cmake ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE dummy.toolchain.cmake
    - make -j

run-some-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build
    - ./run-some-dummy
```

The question is, the build stage and test stage should run on different platform, one on the dev server(x86) and one on the release-like board(arm). I've learned that one can [specific runner for different job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#use-tags-to-control-which-jobs-a-runner-can-run), but in this case, we need to pass the build artifact from build stage to test stage, and i am not sure whether this can be solved by runner configuration. Or i just overthink the question, i can simply use `rsync` or `scp` to copy the build artifacts to the dev board then run some command by `ssh`?

Sincerely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can specify which runner a job runs on by using [`tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) in your CI file, but you would need to have a gitlab runner running on your development board. There are runner builds available for ARM/ARM64: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/index.html

You can upload [job artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) to your gitlab server and make them available to downstream jobs with the `needs` or `dependencies` keywords. Your yaml would look something like:

```yaml
stages:
 - build
 - test

armv7-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build
    - cmake ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE dummy.toolchain.cmake
    - make -j
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build

run-some-test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - armv7
  needs:
    - armv7-build
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build
    - ./run-some-dummy
```

The test job would run on any runner that is tagged with `armv7`. You can tag runners when registering them with gitlab, or in the [gitlab UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#use-tags-to-control-which-jobs-a-runner-can-run).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder if ssh to the dev board on x86 server and run some command is also a valid solution or not? If yes, what's the pros and cons compare with the runner solution?

Comment: So you would scp the test files over to the board and use ssh to execute? That would also work. The cons would be having to script the state management (clean the dirs, copy the right files, etc.) and if you want to have any test outputs/reports you'd need to pull them back off the dev board. It's really down to how complex it is to get a runner up and running vs. writing the scp/ssh script.

Comment: But it seems that the shell executor also need to clean up the env manually? https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#selecting-the-executor

Comment: Ahhhh, you meant the SSH executor! I thought you were just going to write a script to ssh to the remote machine, so my last comment is wrong. Never tried the SSH executor, but looks like there's not much difference between that and the shell one.